# How to create space between subplots?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, subplot

The title pretty much says it all.
I have a notebook containing two subplots and would like to create some space between them. 
They look too close to one another per say.

Answer (score 15):

With [`matplotlib.Figure.subplots_adjust`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
ax2.plot([1,2,3], [3,2,1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

increasing the width can be done with the `wspace` parameter:

```
... # same setup as before
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to have even more control over the positioning of the `axes` then you can specify the offset (bottom and left) and the extend (width and height) of each of the axes as percentages of the figure.

It involves a bit of calculation to get right though:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# All have the same lower border, height and width, only the distance to
# the left end of the figure differs
bottom = 0.05
height = 0.9
width = 0.15  # * 4 = 0.6 - minus the 0.1 padding 0.3 left for space
left1, left2, left3, left4 = 0.05, 0.25, 1 - 0.25 - width, 1 - 0.05 - width

rectangle1 = [left1, bottom, width, height]
rectangle2 = [left2, bottom, width, height]
rectangle3 = [left3, bottom, width, height]
rectangle4 = [left4, bottom, width, height]

# Create a 8 x 8 (quadratic) figure
plt.figure(1, figsize=(8, 8))

// Create 4 axes their position and extend is defined by the rectangles
ax1 = plt.axes(rectangle1)
ax2 = plt.axes(rectangle2)
ax3 = plt.axes(rectangle3)
ax4 = plt.axes(rectangle4)

# Let's display something in these axes.
ax1.plot([1,2,3,4])
ax2.plot([4,3,2,1])
ax3.plot([4,3,2,1])
ax4.plot([1,2,3,4])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That narrowed the plots. Is there a way to only increase the space?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout No, because the figure size is fixed. So if you only want to increase the space you have to increase the figure size **and** the wspace.

Comment: how to do this between only two if having four?

Comment: @ItsmeJulian I updated the answer. Generally it's probably better to ask a new question - but I wanted to add a more general approach anyway so thank you for the reminder :)